# How to add or delete a line below the word [persistence] using a shell script

Tags: shell

How can I add or delete the line below the word `[persistence]` in a file using shell programming. I would like to add a line, if `[persistence]` exists and my line is no already present. If my line already exists I would like to remove it and stop the script.

For example: I want to add `myname@satvik` below `[persistence]` so that it will look like:

```
[persistence]

myname@satvik
```

and if this line already exists

```
[persistence]

myname@satvik
```

then I would like to delete the line `myname@satvik` from the file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I rephrased and formated your question. Can you clarify if you would only like to remove the following line after a hit or all occurrences of your pattern?

Comment: @m00am  ... i want to insert the above mentioned line  below the line [persistence] and the exact line already exists below the line [persistence] then i want to delete that line ...so i want to add the line ,,if exists already then i want to delete it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a file like `replach.sh` and put below line

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 sed  "/^.*\[persistence\]/s//&\\
 'myname@satvik'/" test.txt > temp.txt
  sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' temp.txt > test.txt
```

Now change the file permission

```
chmod 777 replach.sh
```

Now run this script

```
./replach.sh
```

To remove the newly added line again do the following:-

```
sed 's/myname@satvik//g;/^\s*$/d' test.txt > temp.txt
mv temp.txt test.txt
#bring back to original file
```

Comment: ,, thank you, but i already have a script in which i need to add a parameter in the [persistence] for some work later once work is done i need to delete the line i added in the persistance

Comment: I modified you answer. Please check it will work for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks again.... i have a file global.ini in that i need to add the line...the first script above will check the line in the file already exists and then adds or simply it will add the line?

Comment: The first script will put the line and if it is duplicate line (if email already exist) it will delete the newly added line so that do duplicate. Second command(in the last section) will remove that line.